# How to fetch an array in $wpdb?

Tags: wpdb, array, php

I have a snippet that will select a data from database table. But I encounter an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I encounter a new error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`in this line `echo $result->Name;`

Snippet (updated):

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submit_time), "%b %e, %Y  %l:%i %p") AS Submitted,
                    MAX(IF(field_name="Name", field_value, NULL )) AS "Name",
                    MAX(IF(field_name="Email", field_value, NULL )) AS "Email",
                    MAX(IF(field_name="Subject", field_value, NULL )) AS "Position",
                    MAX(IF(field_name="Message", field_value, NULL )) AS "Message"
                    FROM tablename
                    WHERE form_name = "Resume"
                    GROUP BY submit_time
                    ORDER BY submit_time DESC', ARRAY_A);

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->Name;
}
```

[Link](http://bit.ly/1W8opml)

Comment: It seems you wanted to use `$results as $result` instead of `$result as $results`.

Comment: I update now with this `$results as $result` but it gives me a blank page

Comment: Copy and run your SQL directly in database. `tablename` does it exist ? and group by order by are two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your query which is you can't use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` before `WHERE`

replace

```
FROM tablename GROUP BY submit_time ORDER BY submit_time DESC
```

with

```
FROM tablename
```

This is your query

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submit_time), "%b %e, %Y  %l:%i %p") AS Submitted,
            MAX(IF(field_name="Name", field_value, NULL )) AS "Name",
            MAX(IF(field_name="Email", field_value, NULL )) AS "Email",
            MAX(IF(field_name="Subject", field_value, NULL )) AS "Position",
            MAX(IF(field_name="Message", field_value, NULL )) AS "Message"
            FROM tablename
            WHERE
            form_name = "Resume"
            GROUP BY submit_time
            ORDER BY submit_time DESC', ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: you're correct. but im experiencing new error, please see updated question

Answer (score 3):

Going to take a wild stab, but `ARRAY_A` will return an associative array

You are then trying to access this associative array as an object

Simple change:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->Name;
}
```

To:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['Name'];
}
```

and the error should go away!

Answer (score 0):

`$wpdb->get_results` returns a multi-dimensional array.
So the argument for the foreach should be:

```
foreach($results as $object=>$result){
    echo $result->Name;
}
```

Always var_dump your objects and arrays before accessing them.